# Rendering Trailing Effect Using Opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

I have to develop a game for my Graphics Course. I came across this video on the net.

http://www.youtube.com/user/stanfordcs248

I want to know how are the hazy/smoky effects which trails along with the cube is rendered using OpenGL and c++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is post-process effects. Basically they first render the scene into a framebuffer object (FBO), then take that as a source texture and perform various operations on it. Among other things they talk about bloom effects etc, which are done in the same manner.

Answer (score 1):

The smoky trailing effects are likely implemented with a [particle system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_system).